# How to make IgnoreCase when you're using the contain method

Tags: java

I'm trying to make it ignore the cases, while using the contain method. How do I do that?

```
String text = "Did you eat yet?";   

if(text.contains("eat") && text.contains("yet"))
    System.out.println("Yes");
else
    System.out.println("No.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no `String.containsIgnoreCase` method of `String`.

However, you can verify a similar condition with regular expressions.

For instance:

```
String text = "Did you eat yet?";
// will match a String containing both words "eat", 
// then "yet" in that order of appearance, case-insensitive
//                           | word boundary
//                           |        | any character, zero or more times 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\beat\\b.*\\byet\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
System.out.println(m.find());
```

Simpler version (thanks [blgt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2685386/blgt)):

```
// here we match the whole String, so we need start-of-input and 
// end-of-input delimiters
//                               | case-insensitive flag
//                               |   | beginning of input
//                               |   |                        | end of input
System.out.println(text.matches("(?i)^.*\\beat\\b.*\\byet\\b.*$"));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Comment: You can strip out the boilerplate `Pattern` by using `String.matches(regex)` with a `?i` flag, [info here](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/case_insensitive_matching_in_java)

Comment: @blgt thanks, let me improve this.

Comment: Where do I put, "eat", and "yet"?

Comment: I think this answer is missing a bunch of everything. When I tried to put it in Eclipse all it did was shown everything as an error. I'm new to java so I don't know what you're missing if you're not going to put it in the code.

Comment: @nmelssx this ansewr requires you to import the necessary dependencies, all in Java SE. In Eclipse you can simply to that by pressing Ctrl-Shift-O (assuming Windows). Otherwise, a little research on the API and packages for `Pattern` and `Matcher` should help you. The "simpler version" doesn't even require any additional import. Both are tested and working within the scope of your question.

Comment: @Mena but in the code it doesn't even say do that if it finds both the word "eat", and "yet"?

Comment: ?i)^.*\\beat\\b.*\\byet\\b.*$" And what about this part? Can you explain it please?

Comment: @nmelssx of course it does, that's the purpose. Will comment a bit on the `Pattern`s but you should do some research on your own.

Comment: "(?i)^"eat,yet".*\\beat\\b.*\\byet\\b.*$" So just put eat and yet where it begins like this?

Comment: Okay. I'm an idiot for not seeing that it said "beat", and "byet", but you should've pointed that out.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
 org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP", "gHi");
```

Comment: Do you have to import anything?

Comment: no since you are using the full path ...

Comment: But where do I put it? I got an error when I tried to put it in IF.

Comment: where ever you want to use it make sure you pulling in the org apache jar ...

Comment: I don't know what that mean. I'm new to java. I'm just a beginner. I don't know what org apache jar is.

Comment: For mena's System.out.println(text.matches("(?i)^.*\\beat\\b.*\\byet\\b.*$")); if it's true, it just prints true. Can you make it print something else?

Comment: in your pom you should be pulling it the apache commons jar...